# Why sidebar is going down instead of right side in single post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just setup a clementina wordpress theme. this is the url www.theumang.com/read-articles-here/the-sea-crew/ . I have enable sidebar to on to the single post. But sidebar is going downside instead of right side. Why is this happening ? I am using clementina wordpress theme.

Comment: If i am logged into admin section and then try to load again to a single post sidebar is on right side. If i logged out from admn section it is again going to downside.

Answer (score 0):

You have some unclosed tags on your site that are breaking the layout:

[Link to validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theumang.com%2Fread-articles-here%2Fthe-sea-crew%2F).

My guess is comment form that has messed up tags that are breaking everything up. Because only there you have table.

Open up `comments.php` file (or wherever the comments are located), and see if all the html tags are properly closed.

Comment: I have checked comments form tags, all are correct ?

Comment: When i am login to admin it is showing in correct format, but after logout it is messedup again ?

Comment: Your site is not valid, some tags are missing. I cannot say which ones, I can only guess since I don't have access to your files. Did you change any code on your site?